# Aplicação .net não cria serviço no windows (sc create)

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, aplicação-web

Estou com o seguinte código:

```
public static void CriarServico(string nomeServico, string caminhoExecutavel)
        {
            try
            {
                string arguments = string.Format("create {0} binPath={1} type=own start=auto", nomeServico, caminhoExecutavel);
                var scCreate = new ProcessStartInfo();
                scCreate.FileName = "sc.exe";
                scCreate.UseShellExecute = true;
                scCreate.Verb = "runas";
                scCreate.Arguments = arguments;
                Process.Start(scCreate);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
```

Porém ao ser executada este método, o serviço não é criado, acredito que falte permissão para o IIS.

Existe outra forma para o sistema criar o serviço?

Comment: Alguma exception? Você está querendo registrar serviços no windows por uma aplicação web? O usuário do pool tem nível de admin?

Comment: Na realidade não houve exception, o que me daria um norte. Ao debugar, o código segue até o fim do método e não apresenta erro, porém não registra o serviço

Comment: Nada? nem no event viewer? Já tentou adicionar esse serviço manualmente e conferir se o problema não é nele?

Comment: só para garantir... você pretende registrar o serviço na mesma máquina do IIS né? não na do usuário que está acessando a aplicação, correto? Tenho que perguntar, porque já vi de tudo aqui.

Comment: Manualmente é registrado sem problemas e sim, será na mesma maquina que está o IIS.
Até mudei o perfil do pooldeaplicativo dando a ele usuário e senha de um administrador

Comment: Então o problema deve ser só o alerta que ele pode apresentar ao tentar registrar o serviço